# CXF Web service client - no data is received on invoking web service

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

I have created a client to access a WS using maven and CXF, following the tutorials [here](http://www.logicsector.com/java/how-to-create-a-wsdl-first-soap-client-in-java-with-cxf-and-maven/) and [here as well](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).
I have tested the web service a number of times using SoapUI and received the results. But when I call the same web service from my client, I always get an empty response. At web service side, I have observed that the response is properly sent, in case of SoapUI and my client application both.
this is what gets printed on console at client side:

```
WS init successful. Service class instantiated.
In servlet Calling service now
Action is -- JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6: Stub for http://172.18.40.131:8080/AccountWithCXF/services/AccountSearchActionPort
In servlet after Calling service. list is -> []
```

Can someone please help me?

Following is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="AccountSearchActionService" targetNamespace="http://webservice/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<import namespace="http://webservice/" schemaLocation="http://172.18.40.131:8080/AccountWithCXF/services/AccountSearchActionPort?xsd=accountsearchaction_schema1.xsd"/>
</schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="getAccountsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getAccountsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getAccounts">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getAccounts" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="AccountSearchAction">
    <wsdl:operation name="getAccounts">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getAccounts" name="getAccounts">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getAccountsResponse" name="getAccountsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="AccountSearchActionServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:AccountSearchAction">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getAccounts">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:GetAccounts" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="getAccounts">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="getAccountsResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="AccountSearchActionService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:AccountSearchActionServiceSoapBinding" name="AccountSearchActionPort">
      <soap:address location="http://172.18.40.131:8080/AccountWithCXF/services/AccountSearchActionPort"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I am setting the web service stub in init() method of my servlet

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
   super.init();
   service = new AccountSearchActionService();
   System.out.println("WS init successful. Service class instantiated.");
}
```

Code piece from Servlet that calls web service:

```
AccountSearchAction action = service.getAccountSearchActionPort();
System.out.println("Action is -- "+action);
List<Account> list = action.getAccounts(param);
System.out.println("In servlet after Calling service. list is -> "+list);
```

If i call this web service using SoapUI with search query 'express', following is the response I get:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:getAccountsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice/">
         <ns2:return>
            <accountId>3067822</accountId>
            <accountName>FBB EXPRESS INC.</accountName>
         </ns2:return>
      </ns2:getAccountsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug this is to capture the request and response XML.

One way of doing that is to sent up the logging interceptor.

Another ways is to use tcpmon to capture request / response and response.  tcpmon works like a proxy - set it up to listen on some port and then forward it to the original service host:port.  Make the client send request to the tcpmon port.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the request and response with TCPMon as well, and found the same behavior as it was in SoapUI. Looks like it is an issue of unmarshalling the response in CXF client. Is there a way to intercept the unmarshalling process?

Comment: How is the server implemented - is that also using CXF.

Comment: The web service is a JAX-WS implementation running on Tomcat7. Earlier it was a CXF web service on Tomcat, but that did not work either.